# .bat file doesn't work | Shows invalid syntax when .bat file is run | Python 3.4.0

Tags: python, windows, batch-file, command-prompt, python-3.4

The ***.bat*** file:

```
@py C:\Users\Universal Sysytem\Desktop\Python Scripts (Automate the Boring Stuff)\Automate the Boring Stuff with Python\TestProgram(.bat batch file and shebang line usecase).py %*

@pause
```

The ***.py*** file:

```
#! python3

print('Hello World, this is a test program for showing the use of .bat batch files, and the role of the shebang line.')
```

---

*When I run the .bat file in PowerShell or Command Prompt:*

```
PS C:\Users\Universal Sysytem>  py "C:\Users\Universal Sysytem\Desktop\Python Scripts (Automate the Boring Stuff)\Automate the Boring Stuff with Python\BatchFile-TestProgram.bat"
  File "C:\Users\Universal Sysytem\Desktop\Python Scripts (Automate the Boring Stuff)\Automate the Boring Stuff with Python\BatchFile-TestProgram.bat", line 1
    @py C:\Users\Universal Sysytem\Desktop\Python Scripts (Automate the Boring Stuff)\Automate the Boring Stuff with Python\TestProgram(.bat batch file and shebang line usecase).py %*
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

**P.S:**

- The respective paths to the respective files (.py and .bat) do not have any errors.
- I also tried `@py.exe` instead of `@py`
- In Environment Variables, the PATH variable is also set accordingly
- I also tried removing %* from inside the .py file
- Reference: [Book: Automate the Boring Stuff with Python (Appendix B)](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/appendixb/)

### How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: Each line does a completely different thing. First you have a `.bat` file that calls `py`, then you try to call the batch file with `py`? Have you tried to just execute the batch file?

Comment: Yes, I've tried to execute only the batch file (.\BatchFile-TestProgram.bat). But it still didn't work.

Output in PowerShell:
'C:\Users\Universal' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: That's because you forgot to enclose the file in double quotes. When the file contains spaces, no matter the OS, you *have* to either escape the spaces or somehow tell the OS this is one long file name instead of multiple arguments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Guys, I finally solved it! Thank you so much, everybody, who answered my question or gave feedback through comments! I am very grateful for your valuable time in trying to help a noob like me. Thank you!:)

### Okay, so the solution:

First of all, I made a slight change to my .bat file/batch file. ***I enclosed the path to the .py file in double-quotes(")***:

```
@py "C:\Users\Universal Sysytem\Desktop\Python Scripts (Automate the Boring Stuff)\Automate the Boring Stuff with Python\TestProgram(.bat batch file and shebang line usecase).py"
@pause
```

Finally, ***instead of running the .bat file with py at the beginning of its location's path, I just ran the .bat file.*** In my PowerShell, I moved to the directory of the .bat file and then just ran the .bat file:

```
.\BatchFile-TestProgram.bat
```

It returned the correct output:

```
Hello World, this is a test program for showing the use of .bat batch files, and the role of the shebang line.
Press any key to continue . . .
```

***Also, I was able to run the batch file from the Run Dialog (WIN + R). The output was the same as running the batch file directly in PowerShell. I just entered the complete path to the batch file, enclosing it in double-quotes:***

```
"c:\users\Universal Sysytem\Desktop\Python Scripts (Automate the Boring Stuff)\Automate the Boring Stuff with Python\BatchFile-TestProgram.bat"
```

---

What I learned:

- `py` executes files written in Python. It doesn't execute .bat files because Python interpreter does not understand CMD syntax in which the .bat file is written.
- Important to make sure to use quotes (double or single) for enclosing paths, especially when there are blank spaces between words when writing paths to folders or files.
  Of course, you can't use single quotes for enclosing paths if you're in Command Prompt because CMD doesn't treat single quotes as anything but a regular character.
- The '@' tells the command prompt not to display the entire line (path or the command 'pause') when running the program (.py file) but just execute the program.

Comment: @ForceBru thank you for your time and feedback!

Comment: @Jakub Szlaur thank you for your time and feedback!

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thank you for your time and feedback too!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that

```
py "C:\...\BatchFile-TestProgram.bat"
```

will try to run the `.bat` file with the Python interpreter. This is an error because the Python interpreter understands Python language but doesn't understand `.bat`/Powershell language that the `.bat` file is written in.

`@py C:\Users\...` is already invalid *Python* syntax because `@py` is treated as a decorator, and decorators can't be followed by a symbol name like `C`.

How to solve this: run the `.bat` file with Powershell (assuming the `.bat` file itself is correct) or throw away the `.bat` file entirely and simply run:

```
py "C:\Users\Universal Sysytem\Desktop\Python Scripts (Automate the Boring Stuff)\Automate the Boring Stuff with Python\TestProgram(.bat batch file and shebang line usecase).py"
```

If you want your Python code to pause (like with `@pause`), you can request user input at the end of your script:

```
print("This is my script, hello!")
# run some code...

# wait for input, then exit
input("Press ENTER to exit...")
```

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, the second piece of code says that OP is trying to run `py "C:\...\BatchFile-TestProgram.bat"`, which will try to run the BAT file with the Python interpreter.

Comment: I got confused by the far-too-long path and didn't notice that the CLI tried to do what the batch itself tries to do .

Comment: Ran in PowerShell:
`.\BatchFile-TestProgram.bat` (Was in the correct location)

Output:
'C:\Users\Universal' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the `py` tags just simple write down files path to the `.bat` file:

```
C:\My\Path\To\stack.py
pause
```

If you use the `.bat` file to run this code:

```
print("Hello")
```

The output will be:

```
C:\My\Path\To\stack.py>C:\My\Path\To\stack.py\stack.py
Hello

C:\My\Path\To\stack.py>pause
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: `py` files are just text, they can't run by themselves. You *do* need `py pathTo.py` or `python pathTo.py`. The problem is that the OP tried to path the batch file to `py` instead of just executing the batch file

Comment: Works where? In the `Start` dialog? Or the CLI? This is a fundamental concept, not a `works on my PC` thing. *Something* must associate *any* document extension with the appropriate application.  When you use `Start` the *shell* will find the application based on the extension and feed the path to it

Comment: When I run the `.bat` file from my command prompt I can see the output I included in my answer.

Comment: I ran the batch file without the `py` tags in it, but I still get the same "Invalid Syntax" error.

Comment: How do you run the `.bat` file in the command prompt?